# Несовпадение длины столбца с количеством строк при использовании библиотеки PrettyTables

Tags: python

И снова здравствуйте. Решил впервые попробовать поработать с библиотекой **prettytable** для вывода данных в форме таблицы. Необходимо вывести цену товара до скидки, сумму скидки и итоговую цену. Код следующий:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

price_table = PrettyTable()
price_table.add_column('Позиция', ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

price = [4.95, 9.95, 14.95, 19.95, 24.95]
discount = 0.6
dis_sum = []
total_price = []

for item in price:
    dis_price = round(item * discount, 2)
    dis_sum.append(dis_price)

for item, item2 in zip(price, dis_sum):
    item3 = round(item - item2, 2)
    total_price.append(item3)

price_table.add_column('Базовая цена', [price])
price_table.add_column('Сумма скидки', [dis_sum])
price_table.add_column('Итоговая цена', [total_price])

print(price_table)
```

При инициализации кода выскакивает ошибка **Exception: Column length 1 does not match number of rows 5**. Вопрос: чисто арифметически у меня количество элементов в списках одинаковое (5), для каждого столбца есть заголовок, то есть всего строк должно быть 6. Не пойму в чем ошибка. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
price_table.add_column('Базовая цена', [price])
price_table.add_column('Сумма скидки', [dis_sum])
price_table.add_column('Итоговая цена', [total_price])
```

У вас лишние квадратные скобки, из-за которых у вас получается **список из одного элемента** (а колонок должно быть 5), этим элементом является список значений.
Так всё работает, если передать просто список без лишних скобок (в списке 5 элементов, что соответствует числу колонок в заголовке):

```
price_table.add_column('Базовая цена', price)
price_table.add_column('Сумма скидки', dis_sum)
price_table.add_column('Итоговая цена', total_price)
```

Вывод:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| Позиция | Базовая цена | Сумма скидки | Итоговая цена |
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
|    1    |     4.95     |     2.97     |      1.98     |
|    2    |     9.95     |     5.97     |      3.98     |
|    3    |    14.95     |     8.97     |      5.98     |
|    4    |    19.95     |    11.97     |      7.98     |
|    5    |    24.95     |    14.97     |      9.98     |
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Большущее спасибо! Все дело в мелочах))